# Create a polygon shapefile from .dbf table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using arcgis 10.1 and have a table "dbf" containing information of polygons.

This table has fields "OID" "SHAPE" "SHAPE.area" "SHAPE.LEN"

there is a way or tool to convert this table as  shp polinos

Answer (score 3):

**No there isn't.**

The way a shapefile is made doesn't allow for that.  A DBF is only the attribute/table information for the shapefile's features.  The SHP file is the one that makes up the actual geometry/shapes of the shapefile while the SHX file is the one that contains the index between the two that helps associate the table information (DBF) with the spatial information (SHP).

**IF....** the DBF actually contained coordinate data such as the location of each vertex for the polygon, you could reconstruct it manually, but unless it was purposely put there, it is very unlikely for that information to be stored there.

Comment: or if you have the shp and shx file also but then you would probably need the prj file too.

Comment: You can manage without the prj file.  You just need to become a detective to figure out what coordinates are in.  It can be a pain, especially if it came from a custom projection but can be done.  ESRI put out a decent book projections with a section about finding an unknown one - see here: http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=231&moduleID=0

Comment: The order of the dbf records is equal to the order of the shapes and has nothing to do with the shx file (positional index of the feature geometry :[How does a SHX-file work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482857/how-does-a-shx-file-work))